# How to cite EMA public assessment reports

Tags: bibtex

What's a useful bibtex entry for reports from regulatory proceedings. I'm interested in citing EMA public assessment reports, but I think this will also apply to other documents.

Here's an example of a document, I want to cite: https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/iressa-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf

This would be a minimal example, that should work:

```
@techreport{ema-iressa-par,
  author = "{European Medicines Agency}",
  title = "{IRESSA (gefitinib) - Public Assessment Report}",
  institution = "{European Medicines Agency}",
  year = 2009,
  url = "https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/assessment-report/iressa-epar-public-assessment-report_en.pdf",
  note = "Accessed on 2023-11-20"
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I include the procedure number? (EMEA/CHMP/563746/2008)
   Should I include it in the title field, or should I add it in another field?
   How will it be displayed in different citation styles?
2. Should I use the committee in the author field or just the agency, or both?